# how to use psliwa/image-optimizer?

Tags: php, image-processing

Has someone use this [php image optimizer (psliwa/image-optimizer)](https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer) before? What do I need to use this library? Do I need to be able to access the SSH command prompt ? How to install optipng, pngquant, jpegoptim?

I have so many questions. Its documentation is not clear at all.

> It uses optipng, pngquant, jpegoptim and few more libraries, so before use it you should install proper libraries on your server.

Help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

optipng, pngquant and jpegoptim can be installed via `apt-get install` command.